# Next.js Font Awesome (from CDN) animation conditionally

Tags: next.js, font-awesome

I have a problem in my Next.js project.

I'm using fontawsome from CDN as the following:

pages/index.js:

```
import Head from 'next/head';
import ToppieSelect from '../components/pages/ToppieSelect/ToppieSelect';

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Test" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
        <script src="https://kit-pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/js/pro.min.js" data-auto-fetch-svg></script>
      </Head>
      <ToppieSelect
        name="peperoni"
        title="Peperoni"
        price="3" 
        iconName="fa-pepper-hot"
        selected
        onSegmentationClick={() => {}}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

ToppieSelect:

```
import PizzaOrderHelper from '../../../pages/PizzaOrder/PizzaOrder.helper';
import './ToppieSelect.scss';

export default function ToppieSelect({
  name, title, price, iconName, selected, onSegmentationClick,
}) {
  const segmentations = () => PizzaOrderHelper.segmentations.map((s) => (
    <button
      key={s}
      name={name}
      type="button"
      className={`pizza-item ${s}${selected === s ? ' active' : ''}`}
      onClick={onSegmentationClick}
    >
      {s}
    </button>
  ));

  return (
    <div className={`toppie rounded ${selected ? 'bg-blue-100' : 'hover:bg-blue-100'}`}>
      <div className="toppies-id flex w-36 relative top-1 left-1">
        <i className={`fa-duotone ${iconName} ${selected ? 'fa-beat' : ''}`} />
        <div className="uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-[11px] font-bold mb-2 relative left-1 toppies-label">{`${title} ($${price})`}</div>
      </div>
      <ul className="w-full segmentations relative right-1">
        {segmentations()}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

For some reason, when "selected" is true, even if the "fa-beat" is found in the "i" element (The icon) className, the font doesn't animate. What am I missing here?

I'm using Next.js 13.4.4 in my project.

Thanks.